# How to add number with variable name?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I want to change the variable name like stop1, stop2, stop3 etc in a loop.
I tried using for loop with stop + i but it didnt work
Please help

Comment: Please add some code like what have you tried till now.

Comment: use template literals   `stop${num}`

Comment: Why not to use object and it props to achieve this goal?

Comment: Create a `stops` array and push values to it

Answer (score 0):

```
var varMap = {};
for(var i=1; i<10; i++) varMap['stop'+i] = 123;
```

I think this will help

Comment: <script>

var keysArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i=0; i<keyArr.length; i++){

    data1_keysArr[i] = value;


}

</script>

How to assign boolean value?

Comment: data1_keysArr[i] = true // false // Boolean(value) // !!value